# Javascript array length always is 0

Tags: javascript, angular

I tried map elements to [] for angular. But if I checked length of objects there is always 0..

```
var objects = [];

this.get().subscribe(
  response => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      objects.push(response[i]);
    }
  }
);
console.log(objects.length);
```

[image]

screen if I console.log(objects)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just do `objects = response`? Also, where is `objects` defined ?

Comment: I cant - objects will be empty - idk why is that

Comment: What? The screenshot says length: 6. Where do you get that it's 0?

Comment: In another file but even if i checked in above code, still is 0

Comment: I think we need some more code to help you with this. Where is object defined?

Comment: Please provide some [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), currently it's unclear how you come to this situation, and what do you need. (for Angular, the best way to create a [mcve] is currently to use StackBlitz)

Comment: @MTCoster response length: 6 objects length: 6

Comment: @KamilKamil That means the code you've posted is working correctly - the part of your code where you find the length is zero is the problem here.

Comment: By the way, with ES6 / TypeScript, if you want to append values to an array, you can simply do this : `objects = [...objects, ...response];` This should help clear out any problem with indices when using a `for` loop.

Comment: @MTCoster look at the code, I just updated.  Whats wrong?

Comment: The `console.log` in your above example will print 0 because your closure hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: you read the length syncronously but you provide the arrays content asyncronously..

Comment: Okay, now that you updated the question I see the issue. Observables run asynchronously, so the code after the subscribe may very well run before the code inside the subscribe.

Comment: @MTCoster okay then how I can fix this?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the object later. If it's not too much, you can put the logic inside the subscribe

Comment: @ShamPooSham I need use this object in another file, so i need to do this outside

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of execution of the code. The subscribe method accepts a callback, which is the arrow function that you have written with the parameter named response.


So, the callback will not be executed immediately but will be done after a while. But, since JS is asynchronus, it wouldn't wait for the callback to get executed and will move on to the next line of the code where the variable will still be an empty array.


As suggested in the other answers, you could put the console log within the callback function to log the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing `console.log` before getting response in subscribe. Just move `console.log` inside subscribe.

```
var objects = [];

this.get().subscribe(
  response => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      objects.push(response[i]);
    }
    console.log(objects.length);
  }
);
```

Comment: Yes but i have to return "objects"

Answer (score 0):

You are logging something that's set later so the preview shows an empty array but you can expand it.

The log will show the item as it is right now; not as it is when you log it.

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr);//shows [] but when you expand it it shows items
arr.push({name:'john'});
```

If you want to see an object's values at the time you are logging the object and plan to mutate it after the log then you can do the following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(object,undefined,2);
```

Your `objects.push(response[i]);` statement is in a callback and that callback is probably called after your `console.log(objects.length);` you can proof that by adding another log:

```
var objects = [];

this.get().subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log('second log')
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      objects.push(response[i]);
    }
  }
);
console.log("first log",objects.length);
```

If you have a value that resolves once at a later time then you could use Promises but it looks like you subscribe to an event that can resolve multiple times so your `response` will only be available in the callback.

Comment: Okay. My "objects" must be array, because it will be used in ngFor. In another file I check objects.length and I little parse this list.

So this must be synchronous or idk..

Comment: @KamilKamil I'm not familiar using Angular observables but maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669871/using-an-array-from-observable-object-with-ngfor-and-async-pipe-angular-2) will help.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that subscribe code is async, so you can wrap this up on a promise. `result` is the `objects` you want

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var objects = [];
  this.get().subscribe(response => {
    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      objects.push(response[i]);
    }
    resolve(objects);
  });
});

promise.then(result => console.log(result));
```